# Finite intersection of open sets is still an open set. Why is the element $\{1\}$ necessary here?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Finite intersection of open sets is still an open set. Why is the element $\{1\}$ necessary here?

I had this proof in my book for the aforementioned proposition. I will sketch the proof so it's clear what I am asking.

**Proof:**

Let $I$ be a finite indexing set and $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ be a set of open subsets of an underlying metric space $(X, d_X)$. Take $x\in \cap_{i\in I} U_i$. Since $x$ lies in each $U_i$, $\exists \epsilon_i$ such that $B(x, \epsilon_i)\subset U_i$. Now take $\epsilon=\min(\{\epsilon_i, i\in I\} \cup\{1\})>0$ then the result should follow quite easily.

**Question:**

Why did the author bother with the element $\{1\}$ in defining $\epsilon=\min(\{\epsilon_i, i\in I\} \cup\{1\})>0$? What purpose does it serve? Surely without this $\{1\}$ the proof still flows well, I mean the most other proofs I saw didn't include this $\{1\}$ here.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: As a finite set can be empty, maybe the author takes care in case $I = \varnothing$, for which $\cap_I U_i = X$ and the proof still works as $\varepsilon$ is then well defined.

Comment: `\min` produces a correct result of the minimum operator. While we're at it, `\varepsilon` is generally the more visually appealing variant of the letter.

Comment: @AsafKaragila . In a more formal style we could write $(\,\forall x\,(x\in \cap_{i\in I}U_i\implies [....] \implies [x$ belongs to an open subset of $\cap_{i\in I}U_i\,)\,)\implies \cap_{i\in I}U_i$ is open, where my $[...]$ begins with "$I\ne \phi$" and the "$\min$" will be definable without the "$1$". At an introductory level, this would be pedagogically dreadful.

Comment: {1} is not an element.